# Underscore JS difference on array and array with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I'm having an array with certain numbers and an array with certain objects, looking like this:

```
var names = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Alex'},
  { id: 2, name: 'John'},
  { id: 3, name: 'Mary'}
];

var blocked_ids = [1, 2];
```

Now I would like to remove the objects with the blocked_ids from the names array. So the result would be this:

```
[
  { id: 3, name: 'Mary'}
]
```

As you can see the objects with id 1 and 2 are gone, because the array "blocked_ids" contained these numbers.
If it where just two arrays, i could use _.difference(), but now I have to compare the blocked_ids with the id's inside the array's objects. Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by using the [`_.reject`](http://underscorejs.org/#reject) method.

For example:

```
_.reject(names, function(name) {
    return blockedIds.indexOf(name.id) > -1;
});
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76swowLc/1/).

Comment: Well I posted it first so... :) Anyway, glad it works. You could also consider @illfang's for a non-underscore solution.

Comment: Ok you're right ;) Answers are almost identical and you were first, so I accepted your answer as the solution :P

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `block-ids` you have given is an array of Ids, You can use `reject` like bellow

```
var arr = [ { id: 1,
    name: 'Alex'},
  { id: 2,
    name: 'John'},
  { id: 3,
    name: 'Mary'}
];

var block_ids = [1,2];
var result = _.reject(arr, function (obj) {
    return block_ids.indexOf(obj.id) > -1;
}); 

console.log(result);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qvwpp/5/)

Comment: complete and clear answer. Thanks, works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Pure ECMAScript solution:

```
names.filter(function(element) {
    return blocked_ids.indexOf(element.id) === -1}
);
```